# Is there a way to fetch the list of members from a public Facebook group anymore?

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to use python to make requests to facebook's API to fetch the list of members from a public Facebook group.
The endpoints I tried to make requests to were:

> [https://graph.facebook.com/{group_id}/feed?access_token={access_token}](https://graph.facebook.com/%7Bgroup_id%7D/feed?access_token=%7Baccess_token%7D)

But I got the response:

> {"error":{"message":"(#200) Requires either admin with granted
> managed_group pemissions or member using installed
> app.","type":"OAuthException","code":200,"fbtrace_id":"AYQVx_qafWlvIZ0ZzIxx9B"}}

Another endpoint was:

> [https://graph.facebook.com/{group_id}/members?access_token={access_token}](https://graph.facebook.com/%7Bgroup_id%7D/members?access_token=%7Baccess_token%7D)

And the response was:

> {"error":{"message":"(#10) To use 'Groups API', your use of this
> endpoint must be reviewed and approved by Facebook. To submit this
> 'Groups API' feature for review please read our documentation on
> reviewable features:
> https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review.","type":"OAuthException","code":10,"fbtrac>e_id":"AQdTT_-ZEiFw4iCXqbD7"}}

I assume I must get Facebook to "review and approve" my application but I mean.. It's just a python script and I'm just trying to do a research, will they even "approve" this? My question basically is is there an actual updated way of fetching the member list from a group using python?

Comment: `/{group_id}/feed` gives you the feed not members. `/{group_id}/members`  gives you members. And no there are no other ways.

Comment: They are very careful about who has access to these endpoints, Cambridge Analytica was also only "just trying to do a research"

Comment: If you create a test group you should be able to fetch the members list, although you may only receive members who have a role on your app until the Permission/Feature is approved by Facebook.

Comment: @WizKid I understand but then how does phantombuster.com and other similar sites fetch group info using cookies etc.?

Comment: @AndrewL same goes

Comment: You would have to ask phantombuster.com. But their thing say "Extract up to 4-5k group members from any single group you're a member of" which is what you could do before so my guess is either they can't do it anymore. Or they are scraping and Facebook doesn't allow scraping.

Comment: @WizKid I used the service an hour ago, it's working as intended... I don't think they are going to tell me hahah, that's what I'm trying to figure out

Comment: 99% sure they are scraping. That functionality can break at any time, I would not rely on it for something you are building.